# changing a nested list with a condition

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

```py
alpha = [[[1, True], [2, False], [3, True]], [[4, False], [5, True], [6,False]]]
```

I want to create another nested list (beta) but only with the first elements of each list, i.e: the integers.

The condition is: I want beta to contain elements from alpha only if it's adjacent boolean element is True. If it is false I want to store "o" in its corresponding position.

What I'm looking for:

```py
beta = [[[1, "o", 3], [["o", 5 "o"]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be acheived using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and [if expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator):

```
beta = [[(i if condition else 'o') for i, condition in a_elem] for a_elem in alpha]
```

The `i, condition` part is list unpacking, similar to [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unpacking-a-tuple-in-python/)

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions will work well here.

```
beta = [[integer if boolean else 'o' for integer, boolean in item] for item in alpha])
```

This is a complex line of code, so we can break it down. The inner list comprehension is `[integer if boolean else 'o' for integer, boolean in item]`. The second part of the comprehension `for integer, boolean in item` is used to unpack the the list. It takes `item`, which you'll see in a moment is what we are calling the nested lists, and unpacks the integer into a variable `integer`, and the boolean value into a variable `boolean`. It then uses a conditional statement `integer if boolean else 'o'`. Expanded, that statement is:

```
if boolean:
    return integer
else:
    return 'o'
```

The outer list comprehension is simply `[<inner comprehension> for item in alpha]`. This goes through alpha and passes what it finds to the inner comprehension as a variable called `item`.